# How to get field name

Tags: django, django-sphinx

Recently i have implemented django-sphinx search on my website.
It is working fine of each separate model. 
But now my client requirement has changed.
To implement that functionality i need field name to whom search is made.

suppose my query is:
"select id, name,description from table1"
 and search keyword is matched with value in field "name". So i need to return that field also.
Is it possible to get field name or any method provided by django-sphinx which return field name.

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this isn't possible. You might look at the contents of _sphinx though.

Answer (score 0):

Well from django-sphinx it might not be possible. But there is a solution -

1. Make different indexes, each index specifying the field that you need to search.
2. In your django-sphinx models while searching do this -

`search1 = SphinxSearch(index='index1')`

`search2 = SphinxSearch(index='index2')`

`...`

After getting all the search results, you aggregate them & you have the info of from where they have come.